# sqlite in-memory db and multithreading

Tags: c, database, multithreading, sqlite, in-memory

My application creates a in-memory database (:memory:) using sqlite as a back end.

I want  my master thread to create a connection to a in-memory database and this connection to be shared by multiple threads. Is this possible? SQLite 3.7.8 is available for download right now.

Is [the shared cached](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) a possible way to go?

Comment: I don't think so since every connection to `:memory:` creates an independent DB in memory... see http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267077/can-i-achieve-scalable-multi-threaded-access-to-an-in-memory-sqlite-database

Comment: @NicolasModrzyk there is no answer to your link. However it is the same question, indeed.

Comment: @Yahia, yes, multiple open calls will make multiple in-memory databases; so, just do one open and share the connection among the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the connection to your in-memory database using [serialized mode](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqliteconfigserialized), then the connection may be shared among multiple threads.

For this to work, your SQLite must be compiled [threadsafe](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) -- this is the default.

Depending on your application, you may get better performance with a large shared cache to an on-disk database, or with WAL mode if you have many reader threads.

**Example:**

```
sqlite3 *pDb

if (sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:", &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    start_thread1_with_db_handle(pDb);

    start_thread2_with_db_handle(pDb);

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you need; an example added to answer.