# sqlite3 in-memory in serialized mode

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I need a(n) SQLite in-memory database which can be used by multiple threads. I've read [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945514/sqlite-in-memory-db-and-multithreading) that I need serialized mode for that, which is enabled with this flag: `SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED`.

The question is: how can I initialize the database in serialized mode using Python's `sqlite3`? I didn't find anything like that [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager).

Put it another way: does the `check_same_thread` kwarg for `connect()` method do what I want, or it just disables thread checks and something bad can happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create multiple connections (one for each thread) to an in-memory database using `sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")`, then use transactions as normal.

See also: [In-Memory Databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

EDIT: In Python 3.4.0, this doesn't actually open an in-memory database, so it doesn't work.